# How to access a static method via a class reference

Tags: java, reflection

```
class A {
    public static void foo() {}
}

class B {
    public static void foo() {}
}
```

I have `Class clazz = A.class; or B.class`;

How do I access this via "clazz" assuming it might be assigned either 'A' or 'B'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is only possible to access those methods using reflection. You cannot reference a class directly, only an instance of type Class.

To use reflection to invoke methodname(int a, String b):

```
Method m = clazz.getMethod("methodname", Integer.class, String.class);
m.invoke(null, 1, "Hello World!");
```

See [Class.getMethod()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and [Method.invoke()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

You may want to think about your design again, to avoid the need to dynamically call static methods.

Answer (score 10):

You can invoke a static method via reflection like this :

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodname", argstype);
Object o = method.invoke(null, args);
```

Where argstype is an array of arguments type and args is an array of parameters for the call. More informations on the following links :

- [getMethod()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)
- [invoke()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

In your case, something like this should work :

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("foo", null);
method.invoke(null, null); // foo returns nothing
```

Comment: You can leave the last `null`s in the last two lines away, as those methods are now declared as var-args methods.

Comment: I find it clearer like this, but it's a good thing to point this out.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access static methods without an explicit reference to the class.

No inheritance here, sorry, so you must either do:

```
A.foo()
```

or

```
B.foo()
```

If you really need it, you will have to do a check:

```
Object o = .... // eith an A or B instance.
if( o instanceof A ) {
    A.foo()
} else {
    B.foo()
}
```

But why don't you just make those functions instance functions, and let them implement an interface?

Okey, you have a class object. Then do:

```
Class c = ...;
c.getMethod("foo").invoke(null); // null to invoke static methods
```

Comment: but doesn't clazz have a reference to either 'A' or 'B'. does that mean its not possible to do this.

Comment: I had the logic originally written for interfaces and my derived classes ('A' or 'B') cannot be instantiated since they were defined as inner classes and didn't have a public class identifier, hence I had to resort to this technique.

Comment: @user339108 `interfaces` **are** the way to proceed here, just make sure `A` and `B` are not inner classes.

Comment: Interfaces can't declare static methods. And for the last part, it's better explained in at least two answers

Answer (score 2):

I hope this isn't making too many assumptions or deviating too far from your question, but if your two classes share a common supertype and creating an instance is tolerable then you can:

1. Implement a common interface
2. Create an instance of the object via `myClass.newInstance()` (class must have an empty constructor)
3. Call the static method from the instance object.

```java
interface Foo {
    void foo();
}
class A implements Foo {...}
class B implements Foo {...}

<T extends Foo> public void something(Class<T> clazz) {
    T myInstance = clazz.newInstance();
    myInstance.foo();
}

...
something(A.class);
```

It's a little bizarre but in my case it proved to be useful, and I began by asking the very same question that you did.

Answer (score 1):

According to my lack of knowledge the need for the requested construct is given by the fact that an interface doesn't offer the possibility of static abstract methods. Here is an example:

```
public enum Cheese implements Yumy {
  GOUDA(49),
  ESROM(40),
  HWARTI(38);
  private int percentage;
  private Cheese(int fat100) {...} constructor
  public void yamyam() {...} // as in Yumy
  public static Cheese getByFat(int fat100) {...} // no chance to be part
                                                     of interface
};
```