# Java Store Specific Class Type in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a command line interface where you can search for products on a marketplace.

In order to allow for multiple marketplaces, I implemented a Marketplace interface. I plan on having a hash map that maps a marketplace's name (ex. Amazon) to a class the implements the Marketplace interface.

```
public interface Marketplace {

    static ArrayList<Product> searchForProduct(String productName) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("searchForProduct hasn't been defined");
    };

    static ArrayList<Listing> getListings(Product product) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("getListings hasn't been defined");
    }
}
```

How would I go about storing a class the implements the marketplace class inside a hash map as a value, and later getting that class from the hash map and call one of the static methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a static method via a class reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203024/how-to-access-a-static-method-via-a-class-reference)

Comment: It answers part of my question, but it doesn't answer how do I store the class types in  a hash map.

Comment: You store it like any other object. More importantly: rethink your design. Why not use regular (non-static) methods in the interface and store regular instances (not their types) in your map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```java
Map<String, Class<? extends Marketplace>> descriptionsToClasses = new HashMap<>();

descriptionsToClasses.put("Amazon Marketplace", Amazon.class);
```

And finally, to invoke static methods:

```
Class<? extends Marketplace> marketplaceClass = descriptionsToClasses.get("Amazon Marketplace");
Method staticSearchMethod = marketplaceClass.getMethod("searchForProduct", String.class);
staticSearchMethod.invoke(null, "foo");
```

Make sure that the static method you are invoking is visible in the scope.

Comment: It is better to use an interface on the left hand side, i.e. Map<Class<? extends Marketplace>, String> classesToDescriptions = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Thanks @RalfWagner. Just changed that bit.